# Add content search web part programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-addin, content-query-web-part

I trying to add a Content serach webpart to a page by Activation feature. 
But im getting wrong web part when trying 
i want **Content serach part** to be able to query content from other parts in the site collection

```
using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb)
        {
            var file = web.GetFile(PageUrl);
            var prevAllowUnsafe = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            string quey = "path"+ query ;

                using (var webMngr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(file.Url, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
            {
            // this is wrong ..... I want Content search web part not query
               ContentByQueryWebPart contentByQueryWebPart = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
                contentByQueryWebPart.Title = "Test test";

                contentByQueryWebPart.QueryOverride = quey;
                webMngr.AddWebPart(contentByQueryWebPart, WebPartZoneId, 0);

                webMngr.SaveChanges(contentByQueryWebPart);
                web.Update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ContentBySearchWebPart` class which is present in `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls` namespace and `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search` dll.

Comment: ContentBySearchWebPart  Doesnt exist in this namespace !

Comment: Added these things 
using Microsoft.Office.Server;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls;
But still cannot find ContentBySearchWebPart

Comment: See my updated answer. The dll should be `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search`. You can find it here: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll`

Comment: You should add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll assembly, then using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls; (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.contentbysearchwebpart.aspx)